# R - Bing search for loop does not fully run - XML error messages

Tags: r, xml, for-loop, xpath, xml-parsing

I've been using a for loop to extract Bing search results for a number of celebrity names ("all$names") in combination with different fruits ("keywords").
The loop per se runs but after a while it gets stuck and I get the following error message:

```
Error: 
1: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
2: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
3: xmlns:content: 'http ...' is not a valid URI
4: attributes construct error
5: Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 2
```

Maybe it is important to mention that my actual list of names ("all$name") contains 195 lines and my actual "keywords" is a list of 101 lines (thus ~20k combinations). I can not show them here due to confidentiality, I'm sorry.

When troubleshooting, the return data frame seems alright, so I assume it is some issue in the XML parsing as also indicated in  the error message.

This is the code I am using:

```
search_results_matrix <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(keywords)){
  search_links <-  sapply(trimws(all$name),function(x)
  paste0(URLencode(
  'https://www.bing.com/searchcount=100&offset=0&format=rss&
  safeSearch=Off&q="')
  URLencode(x,reserved = T),
  URLencode( '" AND "'),
  URLencode(keywords[i],reserved = T),
  URLencode('"')))
  return <- getURIAsynchronous(search_links)

 search_results <- sapply(return, function(x) 
 length(xpathSApply(xmlParse(x), "//item//title",xmlValue)))

 search_results_matrix <- rbind(search_results_matrix,
 data.frame(name = trimws(all$name), keyword = keywords[i], 
 search_results, search_link = search_links))
 }
```

This is the input data you will need to reproduce the example:

```
keywords
## Avocado
## Banana
## Bilberry
## Blackberry
## Blackcurrant
## Blueberry
## Boysenberry
## Crab apples
## Currant
## Cherry

all
##   name
## 1 Julia Roberts
## 2 George Lucas
## 3 Oprah Winfrey
## 4 Tom Hanks
## 5 Michael Jordan
## 6 The Rolling Stones
## 7 Tiger Woods
## 8 Backstreet Boys
## 9 Cher
## 10 Steven Spielberg
```